# Edge crashing - how to get diagnostics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-edge

I'm having an issue debugging a problem on Edge. The page is a search page, it goes off and makes an api call, and populates search results based on the results.

The problem is that, on Edge, after loading the results, if I scroll, or hover a button (which triggers a style change) then the page crashes - the window reloads, and loses all state.

I would love to give a reproducible example of this but the problem is that I can't get any kind of diagnostics out. I lose Edge's performance tools when the browser crashes.

I appreciate this may not be appropriate for SO, but I'm just wondering if anyone has any thoughts about how I can get some diagnostic info out of this.

Having looked at the windows event viewer, I get events with the following details:

The first:

> Faulting application name: MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe, version: 11.0.18362.1,
>   time stamp: 0xceb8cbe1 Faulting module name: edgehtml.dll, version:
>   11.0.18362.693, time stamp: 0x8fd35bbf Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x00000000003687b0 Faulting process id: 0xf660 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d643c62803e159 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edgehtml.dll Report Id:
>   766b6b5d-ac55-4d69-a89d-35c14904f4f0 Faulting package full name:
>   Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.449.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe Faulting
>   package-relative application ID: MicrosoftEdge

And the second:

> Fault bucket 1156610667547880346, type 5 Event Name: MoAppCrash
>   Response: Not available Cab Id: 0
>
> Problem signature: P1:
>   Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_44.18362.449.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe P2:
>   praid:MicrosoftEdge P3: 11.0.18362.1 P4: ceb8cbe1 P5: edgehtml.dll P6:
>   11.0.18362.693 P7: 8fd35bbf P8: c0000005 P9: 00000000003687b0 P10:
>
> Attached files:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER12A4.tmp.dmp
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1499.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER14AA.tmp.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER14B7.tmp.csv
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER14E7.tmp.txt
>
> These files may be available here:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_Microsoft.Micros_971b43ccd9c8ea632623c0c4b9fb5a463caf384e_5e85b145_22e63f9c-1df3-407f-9b26-db2954f33099
>
> Analysis symbol:  Rechecking for solution: 0 Report Id:
>   766b6b5d-ac55-4d69-a89d-35c14904f4f0 Report Status: 268435456 Hashed
>   bucket: 77055a59f2857416300d1b462e9e6b9a Cab Guid: 0

Though there don't seem to be any files at those locations

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? And,  how many search results are returned? Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Here are some things you can try: 1. Restart Edge browser. 2. Clear browser data (cache and history). 3. Using F12 developer tools to debug the website. 4. Open Task Manager and check the memory usage. If the suggestions above didn’t work, try to repair and reset Edge or reinstall Edge.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I'm afraid I can't find a way to reproduce this without the actual site code, which I can't share - though it's happening for every user of the site. I did try and mention in the question that I've already tried the developer tools - no log messages are shown and the crash wipes any diagnostic session. I've added some details from the event log, but nothing seems particularly useful right now

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in my previous comment? As far as I know, if there has large cache or temp data, it will cause the page crash. And, the memory leak issue also might cause the Edge crash. So, in my previous reply, I suggest you clear the browser data and check whether the issue is related the memory. Besides, without the related code, we can't reproduce the problem, so, it is hard to find the real reason. From your description, do you mean the page will crash when you scroll or hover a button, you could check related code, if there have any strange or not.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I haven't tried it because it's affecting every user in the same way on every page - I can't imagine that every single user of the page has a cache issue

Comment: OK, I understand that. Whether this problem only occurs in Microsoft Edge browser? Try to use another browser to check it. If it still have this issue with other browsers. I suggest you could check the related code and check the memory usage. We could verify whether the issue relates the memory leak. Besides, from your description "it's affecting every user in the same way on every page", perhaps the issue is related to the site code, can you create a simple sample (without share your original code, just create a new sample) to reproduce the problem?